# Deny direct access to certain files in server

Tags: flash, http, .htaccess

I have few files in my www folder, namely index.html, index.xml, index.swf and index.js. index.html will include the xml, swf and js files, something like

```
embedpano({swf:"index.swf", xml:"index.xml", target:"pano"});
```

I wanted to block access to the xml file, namely http://mywebsite.com/index.xml will be something like access denied. Since I am using apache web server, I did something like

```
<FilesMatch "\.(xml)$">
  Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

in my .htaccess file in that directory. However, the page (http://mywebsite.com/index.html) did not load, complaining IO error of the xml file.

Is there any other option I can try?

Thanks.

Comment: If you are requesting the xml file via ajax, then it will need to be accessible.

Comment: So you want your flash to be able to access the XML file, but not anything else? That won't work. There might be ways to make it harder to access, but you can't prevent it, if you allow access from your flash file.